# Kafka - Producer Acknowledgement

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I saw in a video tutorial that Kafka Broker supports 3 types of acknowledgement when producer posts a message.

0 - Fire and Forget
1 - Leader Ack
2 - Ack of all the brokers

I am using Kafka's Java API to post message. Is this something that has to be set for each broker using server.properties specific to each broker or is it something that has to be set by producer? If it has to be set by the producer , please explain how it can be set using Java API.

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata;

import java.util.Properties;

public class KafkaProducerApp {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094");
        properties.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        KafkaProducer<String,String> kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);

        try{
            for(int i=0;i<150;i++) {
                RecordMetadata ack = kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("replicated_topic", Integer.toString(i), "MyMessage" + Integer.toString(i))).get();
                System.out.println(" Offset = " + ack.offset());
                System.out.println(" Partition = " + ack.partition());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            kafkaProducer.close();
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: Actually I thought it supported a continuous range of values: -1 == "all" == leader and all in-sync-replicas, 0 == fire-and-forget, 1 == just the leader, 2 == leader and one more replica, 3 == leader and two more replicas, and so on?

Comment: I suppose acks >1 was removed from v0.9 onward: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-1+-+Remove+support+of+request.required.acks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a producer property and is set similar to other properties you have in your code:

```
properties.put("acks","all");
```

The list of all configurable producer properties can be found [here](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerconfigs).

You might want to also look at the broker (or topic) [property](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs) `min.insync.replicas` that is related to this producer config.

Comment: Thanks a lot @vahid

Comment: @vahid does that mean when we close producer it actually waits until we get the ack for all the message? Or we can check somewhere in the code before next or next send.

Comment: Yes, from the KafkaProducer's [JavaDoc](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/e18335dd953107a61d89451932de33d33c0fd207/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.java#L932):
`This method blocks until all previously sent requests complete.`

Answer (score 9):

I think you should understand the **acks** property what has actually done and look at the also behind scenes.  If that is ok, you will see this property is configured **by the producer**.

For example, you mustn't lose any message like an audit log. The following code how we would start our producer config:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,localhost:9093");
props.put("acks", "all"); //We are using acks=all in order to get the strongest guarantee we can.
props.put("retries", "3");
props.put("max.in.flight.requests.per.connection", "5");
```

This is a small but powerful change that has a major impact on if a message is going to arrive or not.

This images that from [Kafka In Action](https://www.manning.com/books/kafka-in-action) book which represents more clear for `acks` property:

[image]

[image]

[image]